# Component is not rendering on changing the select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Whenever I change the value in my select, I have to show different graphs

- if I choose `bar`, it should display bar chart
- if I choose `line`, it should display line chart

Initially the value is zero so it displays bar chart, then when I change to line it works fine, but when I go back to bar it does not.

Code:

```js
const [chart,setChart]=useState(0)
const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState([])
export const ChartTypes =[
  {
    value: 0,
    label: 'Bar'
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    label: 'Line'
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: 'Scatter Plot'
  },

// My select Component

  const handleChartChange = (event) =>{
      setChart(event.target.value)
  }


<FormControl variant="filled" className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-age-native-simple">Chart</InputLabel>
  <Select
    native
    value={chart}
    onChange={handleChartChange}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'Chart',
      id: 'filled-age-native-simple',
    }}
  >
   {ChartTypes.map((e,chart)=>{
     return (
       <option value={e.value} key={e}>
         {e.label}
     </option>
     )
    })}
  </Select>

    {/* </Col>
    <Col> */}
</FormControl>

// conditional rendering the component


    {chart === 0 ? <BarChart
      graphData={filterData}
      filterType={graphFilter}
    /> : <LineChart
      graphData={filterData}
      filterType={graphFilter} />
  }
```

## Edit

Thanks, it worked with the support of the below answers

Comment: Where is the code for `handleChartChange`?

Comment: Please check, updated the question

Comment: There is your problem. You're passing a string value to `setChart` but checking for type via `chart === 0`.

Comment: No, dominik, my select component is working fine and  I already mentioned it works for one of the case  "Initially the value is zero so it displays bar chart, then when I change to line it works fine, but when I go back to bar it does not.

" , but it does not

Comment: Initially you set 0 as number in state so first it works. but when again you change from line chart to bar chat, your state will be "0" so when it compares "0" === 0 it will return false.

Comment: I answered and added why your initial state works. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the value of `event.target.value` is going to be a string `"0"` instead of a number `0` which you check for in your `chart === 0` check.

Your initial value works because you hard-coded a zero as a number.

### Option 1

You can either change the check to not include the type by doing `chart == 0`

OR

### Option 2

You can change the `value` in your `ChartTypes` array to a string:

```js
export const ChartTypes = [
  {
    value: '0',
    label: 'Bar'
  },
  {
    value: '1',
    label: 'Line'
  },
  {
    value: '2',
    label: 'Scatter Plot'
  }
];
```

and make your initial value `const [chart, setChart] = useState('0')`

OR

### Option 3

You can change your `handleChartChange` function to parse the value as a number:

```
const handleChartChange = (event) => {
  setChart(parseInt(event.target.value));
}
```

Comment: I think this condition `chart === 0` is also needs to change, right?

Comment: I stated three options that would work here. One of which is indeed changing the condition to `chart == 0`

Comment: thank you @Dominik , thanks alot it worked and Dominink will u help me with this, I have three graphs , now how do i write condition such that if value '3' is selected scatter plot is rendered

Comment: No worries, feel free to up-vote and mark as the answer to give me them imaginary internet points

Comment: @Dominik I was talking about option 2, if anyone goes with second option then they also need to change condition.

Comment: No because it would be guaranteed then that the value is always a string so the type check passes... no?

Answer (score -1):

try this way, it works for me.

```
//define the state in this way:
const [state,setSate]=useState({chart:0})
const handleChartChange = (e) => {
      setState({...state, chart:e.target.value})
}

<Select
       ...
       value={state.chart}
       onChange={handleChartChange}
       ...
       >
</Select>
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue OP had